# Autocorrelation of signal with offset

Tags: autocorrelation

If I have a stationary signal $x(t)$ with zero mean and with an auto correlation $r_{xx}(\tau)$, then what is the auto correlation of $y(t)=x(t)+b$ ?

My calculations so far:

$$\begin{align}
r_{yy}(\tau) &= E\{ [x(t+\tau) + b] [x(t) + b] \} \\
&= E\{ x(t+\tau)x(t) + b x(t+\tau) + b x(t) + b^2 \} \\
&=r_{xx}(\tau) + b^2 \\
\end{align}$$

The problem is that the autocorrelation of a constant is a triangular pulse and not just a squared offset. What am I missing here?

Comment: To get a triangular autocorrelation, b(t) shouldn't be a constant, but a pulse.Your math is otherwise ok

Comment: in the time domain, adding an offset to series ( signal ) does nothing to the autocorrelation. it stays exactly the same. there are terminology differences in the frequency domain so I'm not gonna say that the same is true in the frequency domain.

Comment: You are not missing anything; your calculations are perfectly correct. The triangle that you seek would occur if the equation $y(t)=x(t) + b$ holds for only for a few choices of $t$ (say, when $t$ equals $-1$ or $0$ or $+1$) and not for _all_ $t$.  With regard to the comments by @markleeds, he is using the _auto-covariance_ function as a stand-in for what engineers call autocorrelation. Thus, his comment that adding an offset does nothing to the autocorrelation is perfectly correct as long as you understand that when he writes autocorrelation, he means what engineers call autocovariance.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: Thanks for comment.  The reason I use covariance and correlation interchangeably is because, atleast in statistics, (i.e. time domain ) correlation is just a scaled version of the covariance. So, any statements about covariance which involve expectations, are equally true for correlation.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing is using `matlab` or `R` or some other tool to find the autocorrelation numerically.  In that case, you **will** get a triangular pulse because you're effectively doing the correlation of a noisy, short-duration pulse of height $b$ with itself.

In that case, the expectations in [Mark's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/58297/80) don't hold and you'll get a triangular pulse.

For example, if I do the following in R:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
acf(x+10, demean=FALSE, lag=100)
acf(x+10, demean=TRUE, lag=100)
```

then the first plot shows what you are suggesting (a triangular pulse) and the second plot is what [Mark says](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/58297/80) (the de-meaned version).

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter: Thanks for explaining the difference in code. The formula I use below where I subtract the second term E(X)E(Y) can be thought of as "de-meaning". My fault for not being clear on that.

Comment: This is mixing up the _autocorrelation function_ of a wide-sense-stationary process, which is a statistical entity that the OP calculated quite correctly, with the (aperiodic) autocorrelation function of a _finite segment_ of one _sample path_ which is a temporal calculation. Asserting equality of the two calculations gets us into ergodicity etc. And starting with discrete-time white noise as your WSS process doesn't help either.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sure!  But the misguided thought that it should be a triangular pulse is probably coming from what I'm suggesting. Thanks for the -1.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just write an answer because what I wrote above about the expectation is not correct and extremely confusing because I didn't show how the $b^2$ drops out.

By definition:

$$\operatorname{cov}(X, Y) \triangleq E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$$

So, $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}\big((X_{t+\tau} + b),(X{_t} + b)\big) 
 &= E\big((X_{t+\tau} + b)(X_{t} + b)\big) - E\big(X_{t+\tau} + b\big)\times E\big(X_{t} + b\big) \\
 &= E\big(X_{t+\tau} \times X_{t}\big) + b^2 - \Big(E\big(X_{t+\tau}\big) \times E\big(X_{t}) + b^2\Big) \\
 &= E\big(X_{t+\tau} \times X_{t}\big)  - \Big(E\big(X_{t+\tau}\big) \times E\big(X_{t}\big)\Big) \\
 &= \operatorname{cov}\big(X_{t+\tau}, X_{t}\big) \\
 &= \gamma(\tau) \\
\end{align}$$

Apologies for confusion.

Comment: No, the _definition_ of covariance of $Y$ and $Y$ is $$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])]$$ where, when the righthand side is multiplied out and the linearity of expectation is used, can be _re-written_ as $$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y].$$ In short, your whole calculation is really unnecessary. What _is_ objectionable is your previous comment that in statistics, the autocorrelation function is just a scaled version of the autocorrelation function. Not so, not even in statistics. For a weakly stationary process, the _difference_. between the autocorrelation function ...

Comment: (continued) .... and the autocovariance function is a positive constant which does not lend any support to your claim of _scaled_ version which implies that one is a _multiple_ of the other.

Comment: Dilip No need to be so snarky. I'm quite certain  that, in statistics, the auto-correlation is a scaled function of the autocovariance. if you don't want to believe that, feel free not to. You're a very good theory guy ( sounds like you don't do much applied-real data stuff )  but it's not necessary to cop atitiude . To anyone who reads thread, my ANSWER  ( not comment. I'll delete ) is correct statistically. It is the formula for the cov of any demeaned process as Peter clearly illustrated. Note that any person with solid stat would laugh at your scaling comment. It's truly funny.

Comment: Oh: and as far as I know, if you simplify an expression out using legal multiplication and addition and subtraction operations, the result is equivalent to the original expression. Let me know.

Comment: Last thing to anyone who wants to understand the formula statistically. You have a series or signal or whatever you want to call it. there's an autocorrelation function associated with this series which represents how its adjacent values are related time wise. So, why would adding a constant everywhere to this series, change the previous relation between adjacent values of the series. It doesn't. The series is just lifted up or down.

Comment: A very relevant one pager that is recommended to everyone. http://jcs.biologists.org/content/joces/121/11/1771.full.pdf

Comment: Looks like @DilipSarwate got up on the wrong side of bed. :)

Comment: Hi Peter: For sure. I think it's fine to possibly correct people ( if they're not wrong, it can still be okay ) but attitude-closed mindedness is unnecessary. I'm here to learn rather than prove anything. and I've learned a ton so thanks to everyone.

Comment: I didn't  get up on the wrong side of the bed, and _nobody_ is questioning the claim that the processes $X(t)$ and $Y(t)=X(t)+b$ have the same **autocovariance** function. There is no need to _prove_ this result as in the answer above, and doing so is flogging a dead horse. What is _very_ questionable is Mark Leeds' insistence that in statistical circles, the **autocorrelation** function, which is what the OP's question is about, is always just a _scaling_ of the autocovariance function. In statistical terminology, this  mean $R_X(\tau)=\alpha C_X(\tau)$ (where $\alpha>0$) .... continued

Comment: (continuation)....  which is true (with $\alpha = 1$)  if both processes have zero mean, but is definitely **not true** when $Y(t)=X(t)+b$ where $b\neq 0$. I have been spanked at times on stats.SE for calling something a scaled random variable instead of a scaled and _translated_ (or shifted) random variable, that is, for ignoring the fact that one variable has a nonzero mean while the other doesn't. So, citations of literature don't intimidate me. Sure,  Mark Leeds' answer is "correct statistically" (which never was in question) and is not a big deal anyway. What's wrong is the scaling stuff.

Comment: Hi Dilip: "scaling stuff"  is not wrong. ask a statistician whom you respect and he'll explain it to you. And I never claimed that my answer was a big deal. My goal was only to show how $b$ goes away and has NO EFFECT on the autocovariance ( i.e: which means it also has no effect  on the autocorrelation ). It's a shame we're wasting time on this because it's not worth even arguing about. All the best.

Comment: My last comment on this but you can reply of course. I realize that definitions can be different in different fields. The terminology I am referring to is described on page 77 of the document at  link below. I do agree that, in some DSP books that I have, it's very confusing to figure out what is correlation and what is covariance and their relation. There's no doubt about that. https://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~wpenny/course/course.pdf  All the best.

Comment: robert: I think you edited my answer which is fine. I don't know if I have to approve it or do something. If I do, let me know. thanks.