# Autocorrelation of a uniform random process

Tags: matlab, autocorrelation, random-process, stationary, ergodic

i am currently learning the basics of signal processing.

As you may know the definition of the autocorrelation is different if you look at a random process or for example a deterministic signal

My question is about the autocorrelation of random processes:

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with uniform distribution over $[0,1]$

so: $ f_X(x)=1$ for $(0<x<=1)$

The autocorrelation $r_{XX}(n_1,n_2)$ is defined as: $r_{XX}(n_1,n_2)=E[X(n_1)X(n_2)]$.

if $X$ is stationary up to the second order the autocorrelation is only a function of $\tau$: $r_{XX}(\tau)=E[X(n+\tau)X(n)]$.

If i generate such a random variable in matlab with the "rand" command and compute the autocorrelation (which should be possible because the random process is ergodic [ time and ensemble averages are equal]) i get a strange result which looks more like the convolution of the propability density functions. If i subtract the mean i get the result i would expect, because i assume that X is uncorrelated white noise, so $r_{XX}(\tau)=\sigma_x^2\delta(\tau)$

```
x=rand(1,100)
Rxx=xcorr(x,x);
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(Rxx);
grid;
title('Autocorrelation function of (X)');

ylabel('Autocorrelation');

y=rand(1,100)-0.5
Ryy=xcorr(y,y);
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(Ryy);
grid;
title('Autocorrelation function of (Y)=(X-0.5) ');

ylabel('Autocorrelation');
```

[image: autocorrelation of two processes]

So my questions are:

$(1)$ Am i wrong with the assumption that $r_{XX}(\tau)=\sigma_x^2\delta(\tau)$? And if yes, how can we compute $r_{XX}(\tau)$ because we don't know the join-propability densitiy function $f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2)$

$(2)$ Why does the result of the first computed autocorrelation look so strange? (first plot)

Comment: You should consider to use the `autocorr` function which demeans the input and normalizes the output

Comment: Consider $x$ being zero mean then adding a constant $c$, $\sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1} (x(n)+c)(x(n+m)+c)$  results in approximately in $\sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1} (x(n)x(n+m)) + (N-m-1)c^2$. That is what you are seeing in plot1 compared to plot2. You are adding depending on the lag $m$ $(N-m-1)c^2$, which has a triangle shape over all $m=-100,...,100$. In your case $c$ is the mean with $c=0.5$

Comment: For independent random variables (more generally for uncorrelated random variables), $E]XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ and so it should not be surprising to you that $E[X(n)X(n+k)] = E[X(n)]E[X(n+k)= \frac 14$ since both $X(n)$ and $X(n+k)$ have mean $\frac 12$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate really? because if X would be white noise (zero mean) then by your calculation $r_{xx}$ would be 0, but $r_{xx}$ of white noise is a dirac impulse (You didn't consider the case for $k=0$)

Comment: When $k=0$, are $X(n)$ and $X(n+k) = X(n)$ _independent?_ So what I was was writing doesn't apply to that case. Big deal. The comment by @Irreducible is spot on and should be changed to an answer.

Comment: the moral of this is story is to NEVER calculate autocorrelations without subtracting the mean off first. Atleast in statistical time series, all those formulae you wrote in your original post, depend on the mean of $X$ being zero. Not sure if it's true in DSP because the definition seems to change from text to text that I've looked at.

Comment: 1lc: There's a long somewhat contentious discussion of this same tiopic at this link. In one part of it, I try to explain why the mean should be subtracted off. you might find it educational since your question is related. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58278/autocorrelation-of-signal-with-offset/58297#58297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I am adding my comments as an answer.
The sample autocorrelation function (ACF) for $n$ observations is given by

$\hat{p}_x(m) = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1}(x_n - \bar{x})(x_{n+m} - \bar{x})}{\sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1}(x_n - \bar{x})^2} $

To understand why you have a difference between figure 1 and figure 2, lets assume we are looking at observations $x_n$ being zero mean. Let be $y_n = x_n +c$ with c being a constant. Looking now at matlabs [help](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html) for `xcorr` for the input $y_n$ we get

$r(m)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1}y_n y_{n+m}^* = \sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1}(x_n + c)(x_{n+m} + c)$

which can be summarized to

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-m-1}(x_nx_{n+m}) + (N-m)c^2$

In the case of `xcorr` $m$ equals $m=-N,...,N$. Which means you are adding a triangle to your result.

To calculate the ACF matlab has the `autocorr` function, which takes care of normalization and demeaning of the input.

Comment: I think a nonzero mean stationary process should have an offset in the autocorrelation as well, namely the squared mean of the process, which woulf also follow from the definition in the question. The triangle shape, im my opinion, is the result of of correlating finite sequences (due to the fact matlab cannot process infinite observation vectors). The zero mean auto-correlation function is what I would consider to be auto-covariance. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, though!

Comment: I can't correct you because DSP is not my field. All I can say is that, in statistics, auto-correlation is the scaled version of auto-covariance and correlation is the scaled version of covariance. Maybe it's different in DSP.  I can say that the triangle shape is due to the non-zero mean of $X$. See the other link I pointed for an R example of the same phenomena.